# How do I remove obsolete values from the TFS Query Builder's Value drop-down?

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS2013, and have customised the out of the box process template. In the course of doing this, the original Allowed Values on a Bug Severity have been replaced. However the old values are still available in the Values drop-down when building a query, causing some confusion for my users.

We have three collections - our main production collection, plus a user sandbox and a (TFS) development collection. The sandbox collection contains a project that uses the original Bug definition.

I have confirmed that all projects in our main collection are using the current Work Item Definition for a Bug, and that there are no Bug work items on the collection that have the old values in the Severity field.

What do I need to do to remove the invalid values from the Value field in the query builder?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you still have work items that uses the old value.

In order to remove the invalid values from the dropdown list, I suggest you edit the work item template using the process template editor, from TFS power tools, and remove the value from the Severity list. You should mark the field with a special attribute indicating that invalid values are allowed, to keep your history.

Otherwise you need to bulk edit (fx in excel), all work items with the invalid value and set them to a valid value.

Comment: Mikael - This is exactly what I tried to do. Across the collection, there are no work items with the Severity set to the removed value, and it is no longer available for selection on the Work Item form. I think it is due to these old values still being in the warehouse, but I am unsure as to what further steps I could safely take to confirm this, or change it.